# PDO fetchAll() gives me stdClass

Tags: php, pdo, stdclass

I am learning about PHP blobs and I got an issue with the data I am getting back.

**Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$**

I am getting this for my results when I echo the column names in the foreach loop

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_blobs";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $name);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $mime);
$stmt->bindColumn(3, $data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

$arr = [];

$items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->name;
}
```

Is there a function I need to use to wrap the results in or am I missing a step?

**Desired Outcome:** => To have all the items in an array so it can be encoded into a JSON string. One of the items is a blob.

**Output of array using var_dump($items);**

`array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["NAME"]=> string(7) "test123" ["IMAGE"]=> string(17861) (followed by a blob)`

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($items);`  i think you need `echo $item['name'];`

Comment: I have added the output to the question - also I will swap the params around. Bad example from the web :-)

Comment: You aren't binding anything here. Remove them

Comment: It looks like the name is called `NAME`, not `name`

Comment: You don't need an array to create a JSON string. You could just as easily use an object (`stdClass`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `PDO:FETCH_OBJ` it would directly return an associative array.

See [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php) arguments for more options

#### Set it for the whole PDO instance

If you want to have this behavior for all your queries in your PDO connection, you can set it with:

```
$db = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, [
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
]);
```

Another way it to set it after the PDO instanciation, with:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**edit:** added global alternatives